# знак плюса добавляет значение но не суммирует

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как правильно прибавить значение переменной "amount"? Знак плюса просто добавляет ее значение:

```
$div.html(
    "Цена: "+  Math.round(c.days*0.60*100) / 100 + amount + "€"
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В скобки надо взять:

```
$div.html(
"Цена: "+  (Math.round(c.days*0.60*100) / 100 + amount) + "€"
);
```

Что происходило до взятия в скобки:

1. `(Math.round(c.days*0.60*100) / 100` - получалось число
2. Далее к `"Цена: "` прибавлялся результат **выражения 1** - получалась строка
3. Далее к **выражению 2** прибавлялось число `amount` - получалась строка
4. В итоге к **выражению 3** прибавлялся `"€"` - итоговая неправильная строка

Если взять в скобки:

1. `((Math.round(c.days*0.60*100) / 100 + amount)` - получилось число
2. Далее к `"Цена: "` прибавлялся результат **выражения 1** - получилась строка
3. В итоге к **выражению 3** прибавлялся `"€"` - итоговая правильная строка

Comment: спасибо за объяснение :)

Answer (score 5):

Дело в том, что вы складываете `string` ("Цена: ") с числом. В итоге всё преобразуется в текст. Интерпретатор работает с введённой строкой по первой переменной. Если хотите, чтобы числа складывались арифметически, то заключите эту операцию в скобки или же вынесите в отдельную переменную, а потом уже выводите, куда нужно.

```
"Цена: "+  (Math.round(c.days*0.60*100) / 100 + amount) + "€"
```

Comment: спасибо за объяснение :)